# How to make updatable GridView in ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to show Employee details in GridView. My client wants that he should be able to update the record without clicking on Edit button to update. Hence I kept everything in the ItemTemplate field of the GridView.

My Database tables are:
Emp(EmpNo, EName, Sal, DeptNo)
Dept(DeptNo, DeptName, Location)

Hence, I have written one sp to get data: EmpNo, EName, Sal, DeptName

Here, I want to show DeptName field in DropDownList. Here only I am facing the problem. DropDownList is not filling with proper DeptName value, but the first field.

My code-behind is like below:

```
public partial class GvwEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["STERIAConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = EmployeeList;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private List<Employee> EmployeeList
    {
        get{
                List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
                SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetEmpDetails", objConn);
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (objDR.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.EmpNo = Convert.ToInt32(objDR["EmpNo"]);
                    employee.EName = Convert.ToString(objDR["EName"]);
                    employee.Salary = Convert.ToDouble(objDR["Salary"]);
                    employee.DeptNo = Convert.ToInt32(objDR["DeptNo"]);
                    employee.DeptName = Convert.ToString(objDR["DeptName"]);
                    employeeList.Add(employee);
                }
                objDR.Close();
                objConn.Close();
                return employeeList;
        }
    }

    private List<Department> DeptList
    {
        get
        {
            List<Department> deptList = new List<Department>();
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetDeptDetails", objConn);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (objDR.Read())
            {
                Department dept = new Department();
                dept.DeptNo = Convert.ToInt32(objDR["DEPTNO"]);
                dept.DName = Convert.ToString(objDR["DNAME"]);
                dept.Location = Convert.ToString(objDR["Location"]);
                deptList.Add(dept);
            }
            objDR.Close();
            objConn.Close();
            return deptList;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlDeptName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDeptName") as DropDownList;
            if (ddlDeptName != null)
            {
                ddlDeptName.DataSource = DeptList;
                ddlDeptName.DataBind();
                ddlDeptName.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell where is the problem, why DeptName DropDownList is not filling with its proper values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution like below:

In the GridView1_RowDataBound event method, I have written the following line of code to map DropDownList with the Data got from Backend.

//ddlDeptName.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

Now, I have replaced the above line with the following line of code, and hence the problem was solved:

ddlDeptName.SelectedValue = ((Employee)e.Row.DataItem).DeptNo.ToString();

and this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        var ddlDeptName = row.FindControl("ddlDeptName") as ddlDeptName;
        if (ddlDeptName != null)
        {
            ddlDeptName.DataSource = DeptList;
            ddlDeptName.DataTextField = "DName";
            ddlDeptName.DataValueField = "DeptNo";
            ddlDeptName.DataBind();
            var item = new ListItem("Select Department", "");
            ddlDeptName.Items.Insert(0, item);
        }
    }     
}
```